# Applying VBA RIGHT to an entire column - Infinite Loop Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have data that I am working to Parse Out that I have imported from approval emails sent in Outlook. At this point I am just importing the CreationTime and the SubjectLine.

For the subject line I am able to use the Split function to separate out most of the data. I then am left with Job Codes in Column B and Position numbers in Column C which includes the text: "Job Codes: XXXX" and the four digit job code number and "PN XXXX" and either a four digit or 6 digit position number. I am trying to use the Right functionality to loop through the entire column and reformat the column just to show only the four digit job code number for Column B and either just the 4 digit or 6 digit position number (the actual numbers) for Column C

**For Job Code Column B:**
Currently my code works for Shortening the Job Codes but it involves adding a column, putting the RIGHT formula in that column for the shortened Job Code, then copying and pasting the formula as values back into the column and then deleting the original column.

**The problem**- Works but perhaps not the most efficient with a larger data set (currently 200 rows but will have 2000 or more)

*Code:*

```
Sub ShortenJobCodes()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Const R4Col = "=RIGHT(RC3,4)"

    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set oRng = Range("B:B")
    Range(oRng, Cells(LastRow, "B")).FormulaR1C1 = R4Col
    Set oRng = Nothing

    Columns("B").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Range("C1").EntireColumn.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**For Position Numbers Column C:**
Currently I have mirrored the above code but added in an if statement using LEN to count if the characters are less than 8, if so then insert one RIGHT function if not insert the other RIGHT function. This also involves adding an additional column putting the RIGHT formula in that column for the shortened Position Number(Eliminating all but just the number), then copying and pasting the formula as values back into the column and then deleting the original column.

**Problem** - This works but seems to take forever to process and in fact looks like it is in an infinite loop. When I Esc out of it, it does add the column and then input the proper RIGHT formula (leaving just the numeric values) but the sub never seems to end, nor does it copy and paste the formulas as values or delete the original column. As noted above I realize this is likely a more efficient way to do this but I have tried a bunch of options without any luck.

I am realizing part of the loop might be due to the range itself being an entire column but I cannot find a way to stop that with the last row (even though I have a count in there).

*Code:*

```
Sub ShortenPositionNumbers()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Const R4Col = "=RIGHT(RC4,4)"
    Const R6Col = "=RIGHT(RC4,6)"

    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim rVal As String
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim selCol As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set selCol = Range("D:D")

    For Each oRng In selCol
        oRng.Select
        rVal = oRng.Value
        If Len(oRng.Value) > 8 Then
            oRng.Offset(0, -1).FormulaR1C1 = R6Col
        Else
            oRng.Offset(0, -1).FormulaR1C1 = R4Col
        End If
    Next

    Set oRng = Nothing

    Columns("C").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Range("D1").EntireColumn.Delete


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

***Major Question:*** Is there a way to use RIGHT/TRIM/LEN/LEFT functions to do this within a cell without having to add columns/delete columns and insert functions?

Comment: Why not just use the VBA `Right`, `Mid`, `Trim`, and `Left` functions to do this before you import the values to the cells to begin with?

Comment: seems like you can just remove anything before the last space `Range("D:D").Replace "* ", ""`

Comment: @Comintern I had looked at doing that but unfortunately there is a bunch of user errors that we need to reconcile so importing first allows us to catch them otherwise we have to go email by email. If you know a better way I am certainly open to it!

Comment: @Slai I am not familiar with the .replace so I had not thought of it. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonLeach it is just the Find and Replace (Ctrl+H). Did it work for what you needed or you used something else?

Comment: @Slai I used something else (From below) but I will play with this as I am learning VBA still and want to learn as much as I can. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonLeach you can't accept more than one answer, but you can up vote them later when you get 15 reputation http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @Slai thank you for the insight, still learning how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you can do here to speed up your code. I'm only going to reference the second code block as you can apply similar logic to the first.

The first issue is that you create a `LastRow` variable but never reference it again. It looks like you meant to use this in the `selCol` range. You should change that line to `Set selCol = Range("C1:C" & lastRow)`. This way, when you loop through the rows you only loop through the used rows.

Next, in the `For-Each loop` you `Select` every cell you loop through. There really isn't any reason to do this and takes substantially longer. You then create the variable `rVal` but never use it again. A better way to set up the loop is as follows.

```
For Each oRng in selCol
    rVal = oRng.Value
    If Len(rVal) > 8 Then
        oRng.Value = Right(rVal, 6)
    Else
        oRng.Value = Right(rVal, 4)
    End If
Next
```

This is much cleaner and no longer requires creating columns or copying and pasting.

Comment: There's no need to use `rLen`, simply use `If Len(rVal) > 8 Then`, or even `If Len(oRng.Value) > 8 Then` and eliminate setting another value that's only going to be used once. All-in-all, though, this is the approach I'd take.

Comment: @FreeMan I agree that it's unnecessary but I was just trying to make the code as transparent as possible. Anyway, I've updated the code to remove the `rLen` variable.

Comment: Very valid point. My comment was directed to OP so he knew he could shorten it up some if desired. Especially if speed is a concern in the long run.

Comment: @J_Lard thanks so much this is much faster and more efficient. I was struggling to do exactly this. Question: how come I set rVal = oRng.Value and then have to use oRng.Value = Right (rVal, 6) instead of rVal =Right (rVal, 6)?  Just wondering why that wont work? (Newer to VBA so I apologize if a dumb question)

Comment: @JasonLeach as I mentioned in my first comment, there's no reason to _not_ use `oRng.Value = Right(oRng.Value, 6)` (or 4). J_Lard was showing the explicit way by declaring variables to hold the intermediate values. Eliminating those intermediate assignments will speed your code up ever so slightly more.

Comment: also, @JasonLeach, _once you get your code working_, pop over to [CodeReview.SE] and post it there for even more help in getting it to run faster. Might not matter with 200 or 2,000 rows, but hit 200,000 and you'll be screaming for mercy! :)

Comment: @JasonLeach You really don't "need" the `rVal` variable, but I would consider it good practice. The reason is `rVal` can only be accessed in the VBA code and `oRng.Value` is a direct reference to the cell in your spreadsheet.

Comment: @JasonLeach I would also expect Scott's answer to be faster, but I posted this answer as a suggestion to make the code you wrote to run more efficiently. Anyway, it's always good to know multiple ways to handle a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it uses Evaluate and no loops or added columns.

```
Sub ShortenPositionNumbers()    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim selCol As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long    

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set selCol = .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(LastRow, 3))
        selCol.Value = .Evaluate("INDEX(IF(LEN(" & selCol.Address(0, 0) & ")>8,RIGHT(" & selCol.Address(0, 0) & ",6),RIGHT(" & selCol.Address(0, 0) & ",4)),)")
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this out, I got the code above working but as I am learning VBA I would like to see how other methods work as well! Thanks for posting!

Comment: @JasonLeach test this out, I bet its quicker than one that loops.

Answer (score 0):

Or work with arrays

```
Sub ShortenPositionNumbers()    
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With Range("C3:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        data = Application.Transpose(.Value)
        For i = LBound(data) to UBound(data)
            If Len(data(i)) > 8 Then
                data(i) = RIGHT(data(i),6)
            Else
                data(i) = RIGHT(data(i),4)
            End If
        Next
        .Value = Application.Transpose(data)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @JasonLeach, did you get through it?

Comment: I used code from the comment above but I will try this as well. I am still trying to understand arrays (it is hard for me to see in my mind how they work). Thanks!

Comment: being code speed an issue for you, you could test this and @ScottCraner 's one and find out the fastest

Comment: as for arrays, from the content point of view they're sort of a sheet cells portion, with rows and columns, but much much faster.